# SQL statement return one rows, but need 3 rows

Tags: sql

I have a sql statement which returns 1 row back, but I need 3 rows back. 
Sql statement:

```
Select year, sales from store where year between BETWEEN
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)-2 and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate).
```

In some cases, I can only get one year, I want the other two years also returned with 0 as sales each time.

Is there a way, I can do it?

Comment: How is your table set up? Are you querying for the same 3 years?

Comment: What type of DB is it? SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres?

Comment: You should also add the extract to your year if it is a date field. Like: Select year, sales from store where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year) between BETWEEN
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)-2 and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a table variable with all the years and do a LEFT JOIN with "Store" table. That way, if there are no records in "Store" table for one year, you get a NULL value. Then, you can use the SQL function ISNULL to replace the NULL value by a zero. Something like this.

```
DECLARE @years TABLE
(
     year INT
)

INSERT INTO @years (year) VALUES (2015), (2014), (2013)

SELECT s.Year, ISNULL(Sales, 0) 
FROM @years y
LEFT JOIN Store s ON s.year=y.year
WHERE ... -- your conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a need for BETWEEN if you don't have future sales and you can use >= instead. You can create a CTE with the years you want then OUTER JOIN to the table with the sales. This will give you a row even when there are no sales.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT year from store WHERE year >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)-2
)
SELECT CTE.year, COALESCE(s.sales, 0) AS sales
FROM CTE
LEFT OUTER JOIN store s ON s.year = CTE.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which platform so I am assuming it supports derived tables/inline views or whatever it happens to call them.

```
select y.year, coalesce(s.sales, 0) as sales
from
   (select -2 union all select -1 union all select 0 as offset) as y
   left outer join
   store as s
       on  s.year = extract(year from sysdate) + y.offset
           /* adding this next condition might help the optimizer */
           and s.year >= extract(year from sysdate) - 2
```